# Intersection Difference and equal methods Java using sets of arrays

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a couple member method:

Create class IntegerSet as follows: each object of class IntegerSet can hold integers in the range 0 through 100. A set is represented internally as an array of ones and zeros. Array element a[i] is 1 if integer i is in the set. Array element a[j] is 0 if integer j is not in the set. For example, set of integers {1, 3, 4, 8, 9} would internally be represented as:

```
{1, 3, 4, 8, 9}  = {0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1}
```

public IntegerSet intersection(IntegerSet) returns set which is a set theoretic intersection of the argument and this set, i.e.,

```
A ∩ B = { x | x ∈ A ∧ x ∈ B}
```

public IntegerSet difference(IntegerSet) returns set which is a set theoretic difference of the argument and this set i.e.,

A - B = { x | x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B}

For example, if A = {1, 2, 3} and B = {3, 4, 5} then A - B = {1, 2} and B - A is {4, 5}.
public boolean equals(IntegerSet) returns true if this set and argument set are identical, false otherwise.

Could someone please explain to me how to do this.

I already have a union set member method.. This can not use hashset bitset or any advanced things because we havent learned them yet.. :(

I have it completed, but the difference and equal methods are not working properly

This is my code so far...

```
  class IntegerSet{

   private int [] a = new int [100]; 

    public IntegerSet(){
  a = new int[100]; 
  }

   public void insert(int b){
   a[b] = 1; 

    }

   public void delete(int c){
     a[c] = 0; 
   }

 public String toString(){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
if(a[i] == 1)
    sb.append(i + " "); 

return sb.toString(); 

}


public IntegerSet union (IntegerSet d){
IntegerSet s = new IntegerSet(); 

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    if(a[i] == 1|| d.a[i] == 1)
    s.insert(i); 
    return s; 
  }

public IntegerSet intersection(IntegerSet t){
IntegerSet s = new IntegerSet(); 

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
if(a[i] == 1 && t.a[i] == 1) 
s.insert(i); 
}
return s; 
  }

 public IntegerSet difference(IntegerSet p){

IntegerSet s = new IntegerSet(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] == 1 && p.a[i] == 0)
        s.insert(i); 

    }
    return s; 
    }


    public boolean equals(IntegerSet l){
boolean b = false; 

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)

    if(a[i] == l.a[i]) {  
     b = true; }

return b; 
   }
   }
      class Assignment1{
  public static void main(String [] args){
 IntegerSet n1 = new IntegerSet(); 


 n1.insert(7); 
 n1.insert(8); 
 n1.insert(3); 
 n1.insert(1); 
 n1.insert(4); 

    System.out.println("Integer Set: " +n1); 

IntegerSet n2 = new IntegerSet(); 
    n2.insert(3); 
    n2.insert(8); 
    n2.insert(2);
    n2.insert(5); 
    n2.insert(9); 


    System.out.println("Integer Set: " + n2); 

    n1.delete(7);
    n2.delete(2); 

    System.out.println("Integer Set: " + n1); 
    System.out.println("Integer Set: " +n2);


IntegerSet u = n1.union(n2); 
    System.out.println("Union: " + u); 

IntegerSet i = n1.intersection(n2); 
    System.out.println("Intersection: " + i);       

IntegerSet  d = n1.difference(n2); 
    System.out.println("Difference: " + d); 


 if (n1.equals(n2)); 
     System.out.println(n1 + "is equal to " + n2); 

      }
```

}

Comment: Are your internal arrays sorted?

Comment: I don't think so. I have the following methods so far : integer set, insert, delete String toString and union set

Comment: Sorting this array will make your life easier when attempting to find the intersection.

Comment: Im not sure my instructor wants us to do that. he lists all of the methods he would like us to use

Comment: @Makoto It is already sorted :)

Comment: @UmaKanth:  The initial data is sorted, but that's no guarantee that the dat will *remain* sorted.

Comment: @Makoto The representation of the set guarantees it being sorted.

Comment: How are you getting those initial numbers from your data representation?  I can kind of see 1 and 3, but I have no idea how you're getting 4 or 8 or 9.

Comment: Also, could you show us what you did with `union`?  That'd give, well, at least myself, a leg up in helping you out here.

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you show us your code?

Comment: And i know I dont have a main I have to do that separately  in a separate class to Instantiate several objects of type IntegerSet and test all your member methods.

Comment: I figured out the intersection method, but my difference method and equal method are not working out.. if anyone could help? @aldrin @makoto?

Answer (score 1):

Return a new IntegerSet object with internal array `*a'*, where *a'* = *a* intersect *b* such that *a'*[i] = 1 iff *a*[i] == 1 AND *b*[i] == 1.`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and check if both are set to 1.

```
HashSet set = new HashSet();
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); ++i)
  if(a[i] && b[i] == 1)//check if both are one
    set.add(i + 1);
return set;
```

---

Using a bitset

```
BitSet set = new BitSet();
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); ++i)
  if(a[i] && b[i] == 1)//check if both are one
    set.flip(i);
return set;
```

---

If you want to create your own class with setters and getters :

```
public static class MySet
{
 int []arr;
 MySet(int n)
 {
   arr = new arr[n];
 }
 public void flip(i)
 {
  arr[i] = arr[i] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
 }
 public void get(i)
 {
   return arr[i];
 }
}
```

And then use this class in your Main class.

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
 int a = {};
 int b = {};
 MySet s = new MySet(Math.min(a.length, b.length));

for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); ++i)
 if(a[i] && b[i] == 1)
  s.flip(i);
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); ++i)
 if(s.get(i))
  System.out.println(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: @I31 Then create your own class

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create a new class. Java already provides this functionality via BitSet class.

Bit Set: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

You are basically trying to create a Bitset [which is represented by your integer set] and then BitSet class provides AND/OR/XOR operations which you can use.

Comment: Why you cannot use this? And why downvote? You don't downvote just because it doesn't suit you.

Comment: I didn't downvote, don't even know what that is? Im only a beginner and this is for school and we havent used bitset yet

Comment: @Lokesh gave you your upvote back :) Also it couldn't have been him, need 125 rep for downvoting.